# How can I resolve this YoloV8 issue

Tags: python, computer-vision, yolov8

Can anyone please direct me why Im getting this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\runpy.py", line 288, in run_path        
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code 
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code        
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "d:\Programming\Pythoncode\Computer_Vision\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    results = model.train(data="D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Computer_Vision\data.yaml", epochs=1, imgsz=640)
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\model.py", line 644, in train
    self.trainer.train()
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\trainer.py", line 208, in train
    self._do_train(world_size)
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\trainer.py", line 322, in _do_train
    self._setup_train(world_size)
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\trainer.py", line 286, in _setup_train
    self.train_loader = self.get_dataloader(self.trainset, batch_size=batch_size, rank=RANK, mode="train")
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\models\yolo\detect\train.py", line 55, in get_dataloader
    return build_dataloader(dataset, batch_size, workers, shuffle, rank)  # return dataloader
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\data\build.py", line 114, in build_dataloader
    return InfiniteDataLoader(
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\data\build.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.iterator = super().__iter__()
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 439, in __iter__
    return self._get_iterator()
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 387, in _get_iterator
    return _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter(self)
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 1040, in __init__
    w.start()
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 45, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Resources\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.
```

> 

```
This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
in the main module:

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        freeze_support()
        ...

The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

This is the main code:

```py
from ultralytics import YOLO



model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

results = model.train(data="D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Computer_Vision\data.yaml", epochs=1, imgsz=640)
```

And the data.yaml has got this:

```
train: 
    D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Computer_Vision\train\images val:
    D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Computer_Vision\valid\images test:
    D:\Programming\Pythoncode\Computer_Vision\test\images

nc: 1
names: ['fire']
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using a command line interface to run instead of a custom script.

If not, make sure you num_workers is set to 0. I had the same issue in my script with workers set to 1, and after placing it to 0, it worked